# Chamar uma nova activity através de um fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho o seguinte código:

Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meus_veiculos, container, false);

    return i;

}

public void ChamaCadastroVeiculo(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CadastroVeiculo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

XML Layout:

```
    <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NOVO VEICULO"
    android:id="@+id/btNovoVeiculo"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="ChamaCadastroVeiculo" />
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.net.alexandrelima.postoonline">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Inicio" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".CadastroVeiculo" />
    <activity android:name=".CadastroAbastecimento" />
    <activity android:name=".CadastroActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

Mas quando clico no botão não chama a nova activity e estora um erro:

> 03-18 15:01:27.177 19877-19877/br.net.alexandrelima.postoonline
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: br.net.alexandrelima.postoonline, PID: 19877
>                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   ChamaCadastroVeiculo(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btNovoVeiculo'
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Esse `Button` está mesmo dentro do xml do fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

Na declaração do seu **xml** coloque o seguinte:

```
<SeuLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="br.net.alexandrelima.postoonline.SuaFragment" 
....
>
```

Para que seu **xml** saiba qual é o contexto!

Comment: Ja esta certo:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.net.alexandrelima.postoonline.MainFragment">

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo fazer a chamada da seguinte forma:

```
getActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

que ai fará essa chamada pela activity que tem o seu fragment...